# How to use store and use session variables across pages?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

When one page is accessed, I would like to start a session and store a session variable:

```
<?php
  session_start(); 
  $_SESSION['myvar']='myvalue';
?>
```

Then from another page, I would like to check if that session variable has been stored:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo("1");
    if(isset($_SESSION['myvar']))
    {
        echo("2");
       if($_SESSION['myvar'] == 'myvalue')
       {
           echo("3");
           exit;
       }
    }
    ?>
```

This code does not work for me.

Comment: did u try `var_dump($_SESSION)` on the 2nd page?

Comment: How is the session ID transferred? Did you check whether the session ID is the same on both pages?

Comment: Code looks correct.  You didn't output anything (even whitespace before the opening `<?php`) before the calls to `session_start()`, did you?

Comment: are cookies activated in your browser?

Comment: @Neal, output of var_dump($_SESSION) was: array(0) { }

Comment: so the session was never saved. u have to check on that

Comment: @Itroubs cookies are activated

Comment: @Gumbo.  I don't know how they are transferred nor how to check if they are the same, could you post a little sample code?

Comment: Insanity check: are the two pages on the same domain/path?

Comment: @zzzzBov. They are in the same domain, but under different directories. This shouldn't matter?

Comment: @ab11, make sure the session cookie path is set to their common directory. The second page is probably not able to access the session cookie

Comment: @ab11: In that case the current [session configuration](http://php.net/session.configuration) for *session.use\_cookies*, *session.use\_cookies\_only*, and *session.use\_trans\_sid* would be helpful (see [`ini_get`](http://php.net/ini_get)). And the current session ID can be retrieved with [`session_id`](http://php.net/session_id)

Comment: @zzzzBov.  Could you direct me to some code showing how to do that, please?

Comment: @Gumbo.  Those values are: on, off, 1.  Respectively.

Comment: @ab11: And what about the session ID? Are they identical on both pages?

Comment: @Gumbo. Yes they are.  I added: echo(session_id()); to each page (after session_start();).   They both give: e92d1212a93e216e96523ff1e903ed41.

Comment: @ab11: Then my last guess is that either *session.save\_handler* or *session.save\_path* is not properly set.

Comment: @Gumbo.  Values for those are:  files and /var/php_sessions.  Respectively.

Comment: @ab11: Last question: Does `/var/php_sessions` exist and is it readable/writable by PHP? You can check that easily by browsing to that directory and looking for a file named *sess\_e92d1212a93e216e96523ff1e903ed41*.

Comment: @Gumbo. I'm not sure how to browse to that directory (/var does not show in my filezilla).  Probably promising, this gives false: if(file_exists('/var/php_sessions'))
{ 
 echo('true');
}
else
{
 echo('false');
}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reasoning from the comments to this question, it appears a lack of an adjusted [*session.save_path*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) causes this misbehavior of PHP’s session handler. Just specify a directory (outside your document root directory) that exists and is both readable and writeable by PHP to fix this.

Comment: sorry to ask for yet more clarification, but what do you mean by "outside your document root directory"?

Comment: @ab11: Since sessions commonly contain sensitive data, you wouldn’t want the session files to be accessible via the web. And that would be the case when you store them in a directory inside the [document root directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot).

Comment: So, using remote view in dreaweaver, i navigated above "public_html" to the root of my website, and added directories "var/php_sessions".  And then I added: session_save_path ('/var/php_sessions');, add the beginning of both pages.  This had no effect.

Comment: @ab11: The path in *session.save\_path* is an absolute file system path not is not interpreted relatively to the document root directory (where you *absolutely* shouldn’t store the session files!).

Comment: @Gumbo. Please forgive my ignorance, but that means the steps I took above should work?  Creating the directories at the website root means they are off the document root directory, and then the path I used above should work?

Comment: @ab11: No. Since “…/public_html” is your document root directory, you should not store the session files somewhere inside that directory (e.g. not “…/public\_html/var/php_sessions”). Besides that, the path in *session.save\_path* is interpreted as an absolute file system path and not relative to the document root directory. So `/var/php_sessions` would be interpreted as “/var/php_sessions” and not as “…/public_html/var/php_sessions”.

Comment: @Gumbo.  I should clarify.  I navigated above "public_html" when creating my var/php_sessions directory.  It is not inside of the "public_html" directory.

Comment: @ab11: Then you might just have specified the path to that directory falsely or the directory is not readable/writeable by PHP.

Comment: @Gumbo.  Thanks for all your help, but this still isn't working.  Can you recommend a way to test if the directory is readable/writeable?

Comment: Well, I contacted my web hosting service and the rectified the problem.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 26):

### Sessions Step By Step

1. Defining session before everything, No output should be before that, **NO OUTPUT**

   ```
   <?php
   session_start();
   ?>
   ```
2. Set your session inside a page and then you have access in that page. For example this is **page 1.php**

   ```
   <?php
      //This is page 1 and then we will use session that defined from this page:
       session_start();
       $_SESSION['email']='email@example.com';
   ?>
   ```
3. Using and Getting session in **2.php**

   ```
    <?php

   //In this page I am going to use session:

     session_start();
     if($_SESSION['email']){
     echo 'Your Email Is Here!  :) ';
     }
    ?>
   ```

***NOTE***: Comments don't have output.

Answer (score 16):

All you want to do is write --- session_start(); ----- on both pages..

```
<!-- first page -->
<?php
  session_start(); 
  $_SESSION['myvar'] = 'hello';
?>

<!-- second page -->
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['myvar']; // it will print hello 

?>
```

Comment: first call first page and then call second. Thanks

Comment: The original question already has that function call on both pages, and other answers showed it was a filesystem issue, not a code issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the possibility that the second page doesn't have shared access to the session cookie, you'll need to set the session cookie path using [session_set_cookie_params](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php):

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params( $lifetime, '/shared/path/to/files/' );
session_start();
$_SESSION['myvar']='myvalue';
```

And

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params( $lifetime, '/shared/path/to/files/' );
session_start();
echo("1");
if(isset($_SESSION['myvar']))
{
    echo("2");
   if($_SESSION['myvar'] == 'myvalue')
   {
       echo("3");
       exit;
   }
}
```

Comment: i added this line to no effect.  I assume its possible that I should be using a different path?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

First Page

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['myvar']='myvalue';
?>
```

Second page

```
 <?php
   session_start();
   echo $_SESSION['myvar'];
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Every time you start a session (applies to PHP version 5.2.54), `session_start()` creates a new session id.

Here is the fix that worked for me.

File1.php

```
session_id('mySessionID'); //SET id first before calling  session start
session_start();

$name = "Nitin Hurkadli";
$_SESSION['username'] = $name;
```

File2.php

```
session_id('mySessionID'); 
session_start();

$name = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "Hello  " . $name;
```

Comment: Session ID must be unique for each client. Here you cannot handle more than one client

Answer (score -1):

Starting a Session:

Put below code at the top of file.

```
<?php session_start();?>
```

Storing a session variable:

```
<?php $_SESSION['id']=10; ?>
```

To Check if data stored in session variable:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty(isset($_SESSION['id'])))
echo “Session id “.$_SESSION['id'].” exist”;
else
echo “Session not set “;?>
```

?>
detail here http://skillrow.com/sessions-in-php-4/

Comment: Have you looked at the actual (3 year old) question? What you're suggesting is exactly what OP was doing.

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

```
<!-- first page -->
<?php
  session_start(); 
  session_register('myvar');
  $_SESSION['myvar'] == 'myvalue';
?>

<!-- second page -->
<?php
    session_start();
    echo("1");
    if(session_is_registered('myvar'))
    {
        echo("2");
       if($_SESSION['myvar'] == 'myvalue')
       {
           echo("3");
           exit;
       }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: and it says on the man page for `session_register`: `This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.`

Comment: Added session_register() and session_is_registered(). I had this problem with an old project of mine and this seemed to fix it.

Comment: I don't think he's worried about code validation right now, to be honest.

Comment: this solution is complete nonsense. session_register('myvar') would register $myvar and would not do anything to the $_SESSION variable. also session_register() is deprecated and in the manual the also say this: If you are using $_SESSION (or $HTTP_SESSION_VARS), do not use session_register(), session_is_registered(), and session_unregister().

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. But I also added a == when assigning the session variable.