# session does not keep the data

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-state

I have a simple php page that set the session and redirect to another page but for some reason the session is empty in the second page.

index.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php 
 $_SESSION['name'] = "Saeed";
 echo $_SESSION['name'] ;  <<< it shows the correct output
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.top.location="otherpages/page.php";</script>';
?>
```

page.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
           echo "session>>>".$_SESSION['name'];  
        ?>
```

Comment: i think page is not still refreshed when you call it in javascript. try manually calling page.php after index page and see what happen.

Comment: `$_SESSION['User']` is not being defined anywhere so of course it will be empty.

Comment: why  you are echoing session when its not set ?

Comment: yes,that is bigger problem :D

Comment: @crypticツ, whats the solution ?

Comment: @SaeedPirdost defining `$_SESSION['User']` would be a good start.

Comment: @crypticツ,  that was a typo

Comment: make sure that domain is same ... or aware how to use session between different subdomain

Comment: @NullPointer that was a typo

Comment: read cryptic's comment and refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489365/how-to-use-store-and-use-session-variables-across-pages)

Comment: @SaeedPirdos What happen if you try manually calling page.php after index page?

Comment: @SaeedPirdost see my answer below, you have your `if()` wrong then.

Comment: **Change:**

     echo $_SESSION['name'] ;  <<< it shows the correct output
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.top.location="otherpages/page.php";</script>';

**To**

     header('Location: otherpages/page.php');

Comment: @OneManCrew, same result

Comment: @SaeedPirdost Are index.php & page.php in the same folder?

Comment: I do not know what are these negative votes for ???!!!!! if you do not know the answer its better to vote it up not voting down.

Comment: Saeed is right why do you vote it down are you a jerk ?

Comment: make sure taht session is set before using

Comment: @NullPointer, it is set I have commented the redirect code and echo the session it correctly shows its value.

Comment: if one directly go to that page .. that time it will give error

Answer (score 1):

Verify if your tmp folder or session.save_path in php.ini is writable

Ps.: must works in both case. calling another page with php header or with javascript location