# How to show a content using current session php and remember it until browser close?

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am trying to show a div content and remember it until browser close. How to call and set `$_SESSION` using php?

```
<div class="show">Show content</div>
```

Comment: Try search on google, and you will get 100 examples of $_SESSION usages and how to.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the answer is explained a thousand+ times on the internet and very easy to find with little googling.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489365/how-to-use-store-and-use-session-variables-across-pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!--HTML PART-->
<form method="post">
 <input type="submit" name="setSession" value="Set Session" />
</form>

<!--PHP PART-->
<?php
if(isset($_POST['setSession'])) {
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['set'] = true;
}
?>
```

Above is the page that will set the session.
Underneath is the content that you want to hide/show when the session is set or not set.

```
<!--YOUR PAGE-->
<?php
if($_SESSION['set']) {
?>
 <div class="show">Show content</div>
<?php
} elseif(!$_SESSION['set']) {
?>
 <div class="show">Set the session first</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Remember, always put: `session_start();` on the top of your PHP file.

PHP ONLY

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['fruit'] = 'apple';

if($_SESSION['fruit'] == 'apple') {
//the part you want to be displayed when there is a session
} else {
//the part you want to be displayed when there is NO session
}
?>
```

NOTE: The session will always be set, since it will be set when you access this page.

Comment: I have a question that what is `['set']` ?

Comment: Can i use it without using html part? only need php...

Comment: @userknowmore `['set']` is just the name of the session that I've created in the first block of code, as you can see. It could just also be something like: `$_SESSION['fruit'] = 'apple';`.

Comment: @userknowmore I'll make the PHP part only.

Comment: Can i use only your 2nd example? will it work without your 1st parts of example?

Comment: @userknowmore Check the part that I added.

Comment: Thanks bro but any way to set the session only until browser close?

Comment: @userknowmore This session will go away when the browser closes. But, when you go to the page it will set the session automaticly, so I'd use something like a button to set it (as in my first example). Could you maybe set my answer as good? :D

Comment: Thanks bro but i need your 2nd example thanks bro for helping...

Comment: @userknowmore No problem at all! Glad to help! :)