# Multi checkbox values disappear after refresh process.php

Tags: php

I have a checkbox group in one file and the results that are ticked in another file. After I press submit the selected item shows up in the process file OK, and then the values go to the database.

But after I refresh the process page the selected values disappears. How can I stop this? I will need them to show on a user profile.

I have tried putting the two parts in the same file, but I get the same effect.

Here is the `process.php`

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

extract($_POST);
$check_exist_qry="select * from interests";
$run_qry=mysqli_query($con,$check_exist_qry);
$total_found=mysqli_num_rows($run_qry);
if ($total_found >0)
{
    $my_value=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_qry);
    $my_stored_interests=explode(',',$my_value['interest_name']);
}

if (isset($submit))
{
    $all_interests_value = implode(",",$_POST['interests']);
    if ($total_found >0)
    {
        //update
        $upd_qry="UPDATE interests SET interest_name='".$all_interests_value."'";
        mysqli_query($con,$upd_qry);

    }
    else
    {
        //insert
        $ins_qry="INSERT INTO interests(interest_name) VALUES('".$all_interests_value."')";
        mysqli_query($con,$ins_qry);
    }
}

if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($_POST['interests'] as $value) {
        echo "<li>$value</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
} else {
    echo "none";
}
?> 
<form action="checkbox1.php" method="post">
<table width="900">
<tr>
    <td width="300"><label><h3><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]"  value="option1" <?php if(isset($_POST['interests'])) { foreach($_POST['interests'] as $tmp) { if($tmp == "") { echo "checked=\"checked\"option1"; break; }}} ?>/>&nbsp;&nbsp;option1</h3></label></td>
    <td width="300"><label><h3><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="option2" <?php if(isset($_POST['interests'])) { foreach($_POST['interests'] as $tmp) { if($tmp == "") { echo "checked=\"checked\"option2"; break; }}} ?>/>&nbsp;&nbsp;option2</h3></label></td>
    <td width="300"><label><h3><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="option3" <?php if(isset($_POST['interests'])) { foreach($_POST['interests'] as $tmp) { if($tmp == "") { echo "checked=\"checked\"option3"; break; }}} ?>/>&nbsp;&nbsp;option3</h3></label></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<?php if(in_array("option1", $_POST['interests'])) echo "checked"; ?>`
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp
check out the tutorial for more info..

in your usage

```
<td width="300"><label><h3><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="option3" <?php if(in_array("option3", $_POST['interests'])) echo "checked"; ?> />&nbsp;&nbsp;option3</h3></label></td>
```

Comment: Thankyou ill have a look at that now :)

Comment: yup sure.. will wait for your response on this then.. :)

Comment: when i put the above in it brought expect 2 parameters errors

Comment: Yup, in_array expects 2 parameters, first parameter string needle, and second parameter the array to search in. Here in your case, 1st parameter is checkbox value, and the second is the post array of checkbox. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify and set the checkbox using the following logic:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['interests']) && in_array("option1", $_POST['interests'])){
        echo " checked='checked'";
    }
?>
```

Here's the reference:

- [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

So your code should be like this:

```
// your code

<tr>
<td width="300"><label><h3><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]"  value="option1" <?php if(isset($_POST['interests']) && in_array("option1", $_POST['interests'])){ echo " checked='checked'"; } ?>/>&nbsp;&nbsp;option1</h3></label></td>
<td width="300"><label><h3><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="option2" <?php if(isset($_POST['interests']) && in_array("option2", $_POST['interests'])){ echo " checked='checked'"; } ?>/>&nbsp;&nbsp;option2</h3></label></td>
<td width="300"><label><h3><input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="option3" <?php if(isset($_POST['interests']) && in_array("option3", $_POST['interests'])){ echo " checked='checked'"; } ?>/>&nbsp;&nbsp;option3</h3></label></td>
</tr>

// your code
```

Comment: i have put the code in above when i put this in a click submit and the values show on process.php  like below     option1
    option2
    option3  but if i click refresh on process.php instewad of option1, option2, option3 i get none

Comment: @janicerobinson *...like below* ? What's the problem now?

Comment: i have put the code in above when i put this in a click submit and the values show on process.php like below option1 option2 option3 but if i click refresh on process.php instewad of option1, option2, option3 i get none

Comment: @janicerobinson That's what it does. When you hit submit, it shows everything as expected because `$_POST` variables are all set. And when you refreshes the page again, all the `$_POST` variables will get lost. For your purpose, store the values in session variables and then crosscheck against checkbox values.

Comment: just googled set variables and came to w3 schools and before i do the set variables being as there is more than one option do i do it like this hun  $_SESSION["interests"] = "option1, option2, option3";

Comment: @janicerobinson [Official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) is always a good place to start. In addition, refer [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489365/how-to-use-store-and-use-session-variables-across-pages). Or do a proper Google search, [set session variable in php](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=set%20session%20variable%20in%20php)

Comment: Ty hun for your help n guidance